# How to get the color of a pixel on the screen for Shader (Open GL ES 2,0)

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader, textures

I use this simple Shader for texture mapping in Open GL ES 2.0
I need to add the code for the Overlay Blending Mode.
The Algorithm I understand everything.
But how to obtain the  color of a pixel on the screen for mixing.

p.s I use only one texture as the source

```
String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
        + "attribute vec2 " + ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "0;\n" //
        + "uniform mat4 u_projTrans;\n" //
        + "varying vec4 v_color;\n" //
        + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" //
        + "\n" //
        + "void main()\n" //
        + "{\n" //
        + "   v_color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);\n" //
        + "   v_texCoords = " + ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "0;\n" //
        + "   gl_Position =  u_projTrans * " + ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
        + "}\n";
    String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n" //
        + "#define LOWP lowp\n" //
        + "precision mediump float;\n" //
        + "#else\n" //
        + "#define LOWP \n" //
        + "#endif\n" //
        + "varying LOWP vec4 v_color;\n" //
        + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" //
        + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" //
        + "void main()\n"//
        + "{\n" //
        + "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n" //
        + "}";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't. There is the classical GL blending controlled by glBlendFunc(), glBlendEquation & Co, but this is a completely different pipeline stage executed after the fragment shader - the blending will mix the current pixel color (destination) with the color your fragment shader calculated (source) using the various modes and equations you can set. If this is enough for the effect you want to achieve, go for it.

If you need more control over the blending in the shader, you could render the image you want to blend to into a texture and use this as an additional input texture when drawing the things you want to blend, but this results in a huge overhaed and should be avoided.

See also the question [OpenGL Blend Modes vs Shader Blending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633950/opengl-blend-modes-vs-shader-blending).